# plugin install wants ftp (chown and 755 not enough)

Tags: permissions

I have root access in ssh to my install (and other wp install working) so im not sure what i missed...

installing plugins through the wp-admin interface, it wants me to input ftp. i remember this from before, a long time ago.

anyway, i tried already various things like chown and chgrp everything to the user. 
added user to www-data group
chown'ed to www-data
chmod 755 (even 777 the plugins dir to check!)

nothing works! what did i miss?

Answer (score 2):

yes, of course i just figured it out.
chown = username
chgrp = www-data

in other words: chown -R username:www-data dir_containing_all_wordpress/